# Application terminates on start when including <boost/thread>

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread

In the simple code below, if I include the boost threading library, the program is terminated on execution, the main function is not even reached.

Everything compiles properly with 0 warning, 0 error.

**My environment:**

- Eclipse Kepler
- boost_1_65_1
- gcc 6.3.0
- Mingw (Don't know version, I have the current release on sourceforge)
- In Project/C/C++ Build/Settings

  - GCC C++ Compiler/Includes: c\boost\boost_1_65_1
  - MinGW C++ Linker/Libraries:

    - Library search path: C:\boost\boost_1_65_1\stage\lib
    - Libraries: llibboost_thread-mgw63-mt-1_65_1 , libboost_system-mgw63-mt-1_65_1 , libboost_chrono-mgw63-1_65_1

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
std::cout << "StackUnderFlow" << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

I have no idea what is the source of the issue, is it:

- the way I built Boost/Thread
- how the project is configured
- ?

The gdb traces shows this error:

```
058,965 25^error,msg="During startup program exited with code 0xc0000135."
058,965 (gdb) 
058,965 26^error,msg="Can not fetch data now."
058,965 (gdb) 
058,980 27-gdb-exit
058,980 28-data-evaluate-expression $_exitcode
058,996 27^exit
```

Comment: What do you mean by "terminates on execution"? Do you at least get a message?

Comment: Add `-pthread -lpthread` to your compile/link options

Comment: The breakpoint in first line of my Main is not hit, there is also no output to console. Also, I do have installed all the thread libraries in the MinGW installation manager.

Answer (score 0):

The code needs to be both compiled and linked with `-pthread` option. `-lpthread` linker option is insufficient and unnecessary.